# How can I input variables as part of a ggtitle for a graph within an lapply in R?

Tags: r

I have a lapply function that applies my graphing function to each element within the list of qList (each element is a data table). Each element also already is the name of the disease.

```
volcanoList <- lapply(unique(qList),
                  function(x) volcanoGraph(x))
```

The volcanoGraph function is the following standard ggplot function:

```
volcanoGraph <- function(dataSetOrdered) {
ggplot(dataSetOrdered) +
    geom_point(aes(x=MeanDiff, y=-log10(qColumn), colour=threshold)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(x = MeanDiff, y = -log10(qColumn), label= 
    ifelse(geneLabels %in% 1:10 == T | minDiff %in% 1:10 == T | maxDiff %in% 
    1:10 == T, geneMutCount,""))) +
    xlab("WT - Mutation Mean Difference") + 
    ylab("-log10 adjusted q-value") +
    #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,50)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none",
          plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), hjust = 0.5),
          axis.title = element_text(size = rel(1.25)))
}
```

As of right now, there is no ggtitle attached to it, since I don't know how to make titles for each element based on its corresponding disease (based on the element name). As an expected output, I wanted to label the title for each graph with: "Graph of (insert element name here)".

Comment: Do these help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55194736/786542 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/57362627/786542?

Comment: @Tung, is it possible to do without using a forloop?

Comment: If `unique(qList)` is a named list, you could pass the indices (`x <- seq_along(unique(qList))`) of the list instead of the list to your function; this way you could would have `names(x)` and `unique(qlist)[[x]]` available within your function.

Comment: Something like `lapply(seq_along(unique(qList)), function(x) volcanoGraph(unique(qList)[[x]], title = names(unique(qList))[x]))`, modifying your function to accept `title` in ggtitle.

Comment: @user12728748 thank you! That was perfect.